# PHP Trying to Delete Reference of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

```
$root = new FileSystemNode("~", true);
$desktop = new FileSystemNode("Desktop", true);
$root->children[$desktop->name] = &$desktop;

...

$q = &$root->children["Desktop"];
unset($q);
```

I am doing this weird thing just to understand what is going on behind of this code.

Real Scenario: After creating and connecting objects(in first 3 lines), I may want to assign 'Desktop' to a variable in the code somewhere and after that I may want to delete it. But, unfortunately, it is not deleted at all. I still can access to $root->children["Desktop"].

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always references as of PHP 5. The `&` operator has no influence in your example.

---

*Update:* (because of your question in comments):

If you need an independent copy of an object use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):

```
$q = clone $root->children["Desktop"];
```

Comment: I see. So is there any way to break the connection between 'root' and 'Desktop' by using 'q'? I mean, without using any variable inside the object.